# No commands available on context menu of Source Control Explorer

Tags: tfs

I don't know what I've done, but on my TFS source control explorer I have "No commands available" on the context menu!  (Panic is setting in)

From the Team Explorer I can see that am a member of Team Foundation Administrators, and I'm a member of the team project administrators as well.

What would be causing TFS to give "no commands available" on the pop-up context menu?

Additional info:
I can get to the source control explorer and with additional commands from another machine, so perhaps it's something pooched on my setup (although it was working an hour ago!)

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, go to Tools > Options...
Click "Source Control" in the tree
Select "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" as the current source control plug-in.

If this option is not available, ensure that you have Team Foundation Client installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkout (Mapping is not enough for Moving and Renaming - for that you MUST check-out) those files/folders to your local disk, before you get the context menu on right-click that you miss. 
I had same problem and from the [MSDN official page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/rename-move-files-folders) I was not too much wiser :)

Anyway, I wonder what is the good reason, for which you can not move files in TFS server repository without checking-out those items to my disk. In SVN this is no problem. (And there is even no path mapping in SVN - just CheckOut :)